# Is it possible to select a random sample percent of XML nodes in SoapUI Pro XML DataSource?

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

My response from a API call returns 2,000 patients.

I created a XML DataSource to create a list of properties from the returned patients. If I put the following in the Row Xpath field, all 2,000 patients are added as properties:

```
//PatientInfo[1]/Patient
```

If I use this, only the first patient added as a property:

```
//PatientInfo[1]/Patient[1]
```

What I want to do is only convert 1% of the patients to properties. Something like:

```
//PatientInfo[1]/Patient[Random 1 Percent]
```

Is this something that is possible in XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subsequence` XPath function, specifying `subsequence(items, start, length)` which returns a sequence of `items` from the start argument position for the number of items specified by the `length` argument.

In your case for example to get the 10 first `<patient>` nodes you can use:

`subsequence(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient,1,10)`

If you want to get a percentage of total `<Patient>` nodes, you can use `subsequence` function together with `count` in order to count the total child nodes, and  you also need `div`, `*` and `round` in order to get a non float percentage number, this all together could be:

`subsequence(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient, 1, round(count(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient) div 100 * 1))`

Where this `round(count(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient) div 100 * 1)` is a `1%` percentage rounded, first count all Patient nodes, divide this for 100 and multiply for your percentage.

Note that I don't have SOAPUI PRO so I can't use Data Source to check if it's work, however I use `subsequence` XPath function in other parts of SOAPUI to achieve a goal similar of yours. I use the follow groovy example to check that this `XPath` works as intended:

```
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult

// xml sample to get Patient nodes
def xml = '<PatientInfo><Patient>1</Patient><Patient>2</Patient><Patient>3</Patient><Patient>4</Patient></PatientInfo>'

// xmlHolder to perform an XPath
def xmlHolder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(xml)

// get the 50% of patients (in the sample 2 nodes) 
// with XPath
def nodes = xmlHolder.getDomNodes("subsequence(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient, 1, round(count(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient) div 100 * 50))")

// print the nodes to check that only 2 first
// patient nodes where selected by the xpath
nodes.each{ n -> log.info printDocument(n)}

// this function is to print xml as string
// it's purpose it's only to log the info
def printDocument(node) { 
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer()
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer))
    return writer.getBuffer().toString()
}
```

## EDIT BASED ON OP COMMENT:

About your new requirement I think that there is no random function in XPath, however you can try with `unordered(items)` function to get `<patient>` unordered, however the randomness of this function depends on implementation, and I'm not sure if it works correctly in SOAPUI, the expression could be:

```
subsequence(unordered(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient), 1, round(count(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient) div 100 * 50))
```

Another possibility is use groovy to fill your Data Source, combining groovy to get a random number to use as start point for `subsequence` function and `XPath` to get the `<patient>` nodes. If you have your response XML in a Test Step you can modify my previous example to apply directly the `XPath` to it, the code could be:

```
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult
import java.util.Random

// random number
def random = new Random();
// random as start point for subsequence
// use a number which doesn't exceed the number of patient nodes...
// you can use count(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient) to know the max number however
// you have to use a less number to start...
def start = random.nextInt(500) 

// define the xpath to get 50% of patients starting
// to get patients from a random point in array
def xpath = 'subsequence(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient,' + start +', round(count(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient) div 100 * 50))'

// access test request response 
def response = context.expand('${YourRequestTestName#response}')

// xmlHolder to perform an XPath
def xmlHolder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder(response)

// get nodes
def nodes = xmlHolder.getDomNodes(xpath)

// print the nodes to check that only 2 first
// patient nodes where selected by the xpath
nodes.each{ n -> log.info printDocument(n)}

// this function is to print xml as string
// it's purpose it's only to log the info
def printDocument(node) { 
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer()
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer))
    return writer.getBuffer().toString()
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: This works perfectly for being able to select the first 1%.  Thank you!  I was hoping to take a random sample of 1% so that each time the test was run there was a chance that different patients were evaluated.  Would you know how to add randomness to this?

Comment: @MattJoe about your new question I think that there is no random function in XPath, however you can try with `unordered(items)` function to get <patient> unordered... however the randomness of this function depends on implementation, and I'm not sure if it works correctly in soapui, the expression could be: `subsequence(unordered(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient), 1, round(count(//PatientInfo[1]/Patient) div 100 * 50))`.

Comment: @MattJoe another possibility is to use groovy to fill your Data Source... I will update my answer with both comments.